# jquery - is there any plug-in for this function?

Tags: jquery, iphone, scroll, menu

I'm on developing hybrid app based on jquery, bootstrap.
For this page, on the center part (I marked it as red.), there's somewhat menu that is vertical flow. it has to move so the one I select has to be on the center of that area.

It's too common way to select something in IOS, so I thought there would be similar code that could be done through jquery but failed to find.

Please do you have any thing similar to this function? It's OK to use jquery mobile or jquery ui as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No required any js plugin you can achieve it by CSS3 and HTML 5

#### Simply check below Example and CSS

```css
p  {
  width:200px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, 
    left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,0)), to(rgba(0,0,0,1)));
  }

div {
    background-color: lightblue;
    background-image: url(http://media02.hongkiat.com/ww-flower-wallpapers/roundflower.jpg);
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div><p>Don't be ashamed to weep; 'tis right to grieve. Tears are only water, and flowers, trees, and fruit cannot grow without water. But there must be sunlight also.</p></div>
```